# PreLoading in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, animated-gif, preload

i really want to how preloading works in asp.net?
for example when click on a button , an animated gif appears and after some seconds a panel or div appears!  (like in many places in facebook)
how can i do that in asp.net?
(is jquery necessary for doing this job?  if yes, which plugins?)

Comment: How it's done in ASP.NET: [UpdatePanels](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx). How it's done correctly is a different question.

Comment: @Jim Schubert  Thanks for comment - i know update panels are for callbacks - but it seems those hidden panels or divs appears with some effects like jquery does - would you plz show me an example with update panels !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is during page about to load

```
 protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        pnlLoading.Visible = true;
    }
```

Second when I have update panel I use Update Progress to automatically handle it.

Third is for ajax calls using jQuery.
When I'm about to make an ajax call I use this

```
$('#<%=updProgress.ClientID %>').css("display", "block");
```

and when the ajax call is finish, I use this

```
 $('#<%=updProgress.ClientID %>').css("display", "none");
```

Here are my loading indicator in the markup. These two are placed right after the body tag.

```
  <asp:Panel ID="pnlLoading" runat="server" Visible="true">
    <div class="progressBackgroundFilter">
    </div>
    <div class="processMessage">
        <img src="/_layouts/Img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" runat="server">
    <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="progressBackgroundFilter">
        </div>
        <div class="processMessage">
            <img src="/_layouts/Img/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading" />
        </div>
    </ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
```

And when the page are loaded I use this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var objdiv = $('#<%=pnlLoading.ClientID%>');
        if (objdiv) {
            objdiv.css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
        $('#<%=updProgress.ClientID%>').css("display", "none");     
    });
```

Hope this helps

Comment: would you plz some explain about your codes! / why that panel and UpdateProgress has the same contents and why did you use both of them?